# Windows 7 lost after boot repair on 17.10

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, 17.10, boot-repair

I originally had Windows 7, then installed Ubuntu 16.04 alongside Windows, on a separate partition. After I updated to 17.10, my Win7 became unbootable, but was still in the Grub list (if I tried to run Win7, it stopped with a black screen and a blinking cursor). I waited with the solution as I was writing my thesis last month, I didn't want to accidentaly mess up everything. Now I wanted to repair the error, but when I ran boot-repair, my Win7 disappeared from the Grub list. I ran it several times with several different settings (like boot Win7 as default) but no changes.

My boot-repair pastebin: http://paste.ubuntu.com/26188875/

Tried updating Grub, no success.

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: do you have the ntfs-3g installed?

Comment: seems you had faststart  or windows in hibernation when you updated ... now you cant get back into windows ... you may have to get a windows 7 cd and load that and try the repair option .. this may get the windows bootloader back but then you wont be able to boot into Ubuntu anymore .. once you get back into windows make sure faststart is disabled and make sure you shut it full down and then try the boot repair in ubuntu again when your ntfs drive isn't 'locked' by windows

Comment: @ravery: No, as far as I know.

Comment: @JohnOrion: I just tried it. The Win7 repair said that it found an error in system startup settings, and I chose to repair it, but when I restarted, everything remained the same.

Comment: sorry .. that would have been the thing I would have tried and if it didn't work I would be just as lost as you are now .. sorry I don't know how to get you back into windows but I believe getting back in and changing those settings and making sure you arent in hibernate would have solved it .. there is a way to add the menu item to the grub menu.. I looked into it a long time ago but it was complicated and I don't remember how it was done .. you may search this forum for `adding a grub menu item` or something

Comment: @JohnOrion: I did another repair with the built-in windows application. Looks like now I'm locked out of my linux account too (authorization error). Oh well, I have to handle that first.

Comment: ubuntu needs ntfs-3g in order to read ntfs partitions.

Comment: @ravery: I installed it and done a boot repair, now it works. Thanks a lot!